# How to create a choice field from many to many connection

Tags: django

In my Django model I have a many to many connection. I would also like to have the option of selecting a primary diagnosis from the connected diagnoses.

```
class Case(models.Model):
    diagnoses_all_icd_10 = models.ManyToManyField('ICD10')
```

How can I create a choice field that displays only the associated diagnoses for selection? It is important that the solution also works in the Django admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `through` argument works for you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

In your case:

```
class Case(models.Model):
    diagnoses_all_icd_10 = models.ManyToManyField(ICD10, through='DiagnoseOrder')

class DiagnoseOrder(models.Model):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    icd_10 = models.ForeignKey(ICD10, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_primary = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If not self.is_primary you won't need further query
        if self.is_primary:
            # Query if there is a primary order related to this case
            existing_primary = DiagnoseOrder.objects.filter(is_primary=True, case=self.case).first()
            if existing_primary:
                # You can change existing primary's status *up to your need
                existing_primary.is_primary = False
                existing_primary.save()
        super(DiagnoseOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, you can use InlineModelAdmin for Django admin customization.

Further reading:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.TabularInline

Comment: Looks like a good solution. Is there a way to ensure that only one of the connections is is_primary=true?

Comment: Yes, you can add a pre-save hook to relation model. This is not the optimal solution but if you are going to use Django admin, you don't have many options.

Comment: And I just add a pre-save hook example to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts. I tested your solution and it works. But I am still a bit dissatisfied, it seems to me something like shooting with cannons at sparrows (in this case a boolean field). 
Previously I had a simple SalmonellaMixin field that worked great. 
Isn't there any hack to fill an choices field with a query?

Comment: I like your metaphor :) what you want to do is really tricky. Check the following post, it may give you an idea. http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/